# Bounding a ratio of a Frobenius norm sum to determinant of a Jacobian product

Tags: determinant, upper-lower-bounds

Let $A$ be a real square matrix with non-zero determinant. Define the quantity $C(A)$ by
$$C(A) = d! \sum_{i=0}^{d-1} {d\choose i} \|A\|_F^i.$$
Consider now the ratio $B(A) = C(A)^2/|\det A|$.

**General question** Is $B(A)$ bounded from above?
This is perhaps too general, so let's think about a more specific case.

**Specific case**
Suppose $A=D\phi^T D\phi$ for some smooth function $\phi$ on an openset $U\subset \mathbb{R}^d$, where $D\phi$ is the Jacobian matrix. Further suppose that $\|D\phi(u)\|_F\leq 1$ for all $u$ and that $\det A(u)\neq 0$. Can we bound $B(A(u))$ in this case independent of $u$?

So far, we can note that $\|A(u)\|_F\leq \|D\phi(u)\|_F^2$ by sub-multiplicativity of the Frobenius norm. Therefore by the hypothesis that the Jacobian is bounded by $1$ in the Frobenius norm, we have that
$$C(A) \leq d! \sum_{i=0}^{d-1} {d\choose i} \leq d! \left(\frac{ed}{d-1}\right)^{d-1}$$
$$ \leq d^d e^{d-1}.$$
Okay, that takes care of the numerator. Now we need a lower bound for $
|\det A(u)|$. We could get one in terms of eigenvalues but these will depend on $u$. If these eigenvalues were continuous over $u$, we could work on a compact subset $K$ of $U$ and take the minimum of such over $K$. Since eigenvalues are roots of a polynomial, and such roots are continuous with respect to the coefficients, this seems fine. But is there anything else we could do that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such bound. The precise functional form of $C(A)$ is not really relevant; the point is that we can make the Frobenius norm arbitrarily large compared to the determinant.

Actually we can already do this with a diagonal matrix; take $A = \text{diag}(1, 1, \dots 1, \varepsilon)$, which has Frobenius norm $\sqrt{(d-1) + \varepsilon^2}$ but determinant $\varepsilon$, and then take $\varepsilon \to 0$. This matrix is even symmetric and positive-definite if $\varepsilon > 0$ so it works for your more specific case too. To make the Frobenius norm $\le 1$ we can just divide by $\sqrt{d}$ which actually makes the situation significantly worse since the determinant is now $\varepsilon \sqrt{d}^{-d}$.

Even without this observation we can notice what happens when we scale $A$ by a scale factor $\lambda > 0$. If these are $d \times d$ matrices (which you haven't specified but which I'm assuming based on your example) then $|\det(A)|$ is scaled by $\lambda^d$ but $\| A \|_F^i$ is scaled by $\lambda^i$. The worst term in the numerator is actually the constant term $d!$ which doesn't scale at all. This means that $C(A) \ge d!$ regardless of how the other terms behave, and meanwhile by scaling $A$ by a very small $\lambda > 0$ both the denominator and the other terms in the numerator become arbitrarily small.

Comment: +1 Let me see if I understand this correctly. Your example shows that $\{\|A\|_F/\det A: A\in \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}, \|A\|_F\leq 1, \det A\neq 0\}$ is an unbounded set. So, no bound exists in general, but does my sketchy argument work for a fixed $A(u)=D\phi(u)^T D\phi(u)$ (with all the assumptions above) provided we restrict ourselves to compacta? If not, are there conditions we can impose on $\phi:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^D$ so that we can bound the ratio for $A(u)$ independent of $u$? I apologize for the multiple follow up questions, but you will surely get the bounty for the counterex.

Comment: @Nap D. Lover: yes, of course you have an upper bound if you give yourself both an upper bound on the Frobenius norm and a lower bound on the determinant. Also if you're willing to work on a compact subset then it's already clear that any continuous function whatsoever has an upper bound. But if you can't say anything about what that bound is this doesn't seem useful for much. What do you want this for?

Comment: Right, of course. Sorry for making this into an XY-problem, but I was trying to prove if $\phi_n\to \phi$ in the Sobolev space $H^1(U):=W^{1,2}(U)$ and if $g = D\phi^T D\phi$ and $\nu(dx) = \sqrt{\det g(x)}dx$ then $\nu_n\to \nu$ in total-variation on compacta where $\det g(u)\neq 0$. I had something like $$|\nu(A)-\nu_n(A)|^2 \leq (d^d e^{d-1})^2 \int_K \frac{\|g(u)-g_n(u)\|_F}{|\det g(u)|}du$$ where $A$ is Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $K$ is any compacta containing $A$. I had shown $D\phi_n \to D\phi$ and $g_n\to g$ in $L^2$, i.e. using the norm $\int_U \|M(x)\|_F dx$.

Comment: That's probably a bit much out of context... maybe I'll write up a separate question that is comprehensive, but that was the best way I could summarize it in a comment. Anyway, thanks again!